# Read a JSON file on Github Action, if JSON contain image => output the image url link

Tags: github-actions

I'm working on something that I have to get images from pull request comments. I was able to get all the comments and save it as a JSON file.

Is there anyway that I can use GitHub Action to read that JSON file and check if the file contains images, if yes, just output the image url link?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PR number, you could use the GitHub CLI to fetch all the comments, and then use grep to extract image URLs.

For example, [this PR](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-capacitor/pull/213) has two comments with an image. The command would look like this:

```bash
gh pr view -R getsentry/sentry-capacitor 213 --json comments \
    --jq '.comments[].body' \
    | grep -Po '!\[[^]]*\]\(\K[^)]*'
```

resulting in

```bash
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8229322/188451036-e9f39fb6-2b1e-4df4-8961-a02435a38749.png
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8229322/189117242-9ee391c0-21bc-4412-9c9f-58a72d867119.png
```

Now, that grep command to extract the image URL isn't 100% reliable, but should be able to cover most cases; for example, if the image description contained a linebreak, it would fail.

If you wanted something more robust, you could convert the Markdown to HTML via GitHub API, and then use an HTML parser such as [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to extract image URLs:

```bash
gh api -X POST markdown -f text='Markdown: ![image](https://example.com/foo.jpg)' \
    | pup 'img attr{src}'
```

The commands could be combined: fetch the Markdown for all comments, convert it to HTML, then extract images:

```bash
gh pr view -R getsentry/sentry-capacitor 213 --json comments \
    --jq '.comments[].body' \
    | gh api -X POST markdown -F text=@- \
    | pup 'img attr{src}'
```

Pup doesn't come by default with the runners, so you'd have to install it first.